# override css properties from angular-editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Angular editor @kolkov

[image]

I use it in another component and when open inspect element i see his css classes
[image]

The html of my angular-editor is :

```html
<angular-editor [placeholder]="placeholder"
                [formControl]="html"
                [config]="config">
</angular-editor>
```

And here is component html where I call this

```html
<div class="vsk__card vsk__flex">
  <div class="vsk__column">
    <div class="vsk__inline">
      <label>Auteur</label>
      <input [formControl]="author" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="vsk__inline">
      <label>Titre</label>
      <input [formControl]="title" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="vsk__inline">
      <label>Date</label>
      <input [formControl]="datePost" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="vsk__inline">
      <label>Contenu</label>
      <dash-html-editor></dash-html-editor>
    </div>
    <button (click)="onSubmit()" class="vsk__classic">Click to submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css for the page

```css
:host {
  .#{$css-namespace}block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 0 0 6.8em;
  }

  .#{$css-namespace}flex{
    margin-left: 23em;
    width: 70em;
  }
  .#{$css-namespace}inline{
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
  }

  .#{$css-namespace}classic{
    background-color: #21619d;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px -1px #0003, 0 1px 1px #00000024, 0 1px 3px #0000001f;
    border: #21619d;
    color: #fff;
    height: 3em;
    width: 7em;
    align-self: end;
    margin-top: 2em;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
```

The problem is that i need to do some modification for my editor and I don't manage to override the properties. I made ctrl+shift+f to search in hole project but nothing happened.

When I inspect the html code I have this structure
[image]
What should I  WITH ::ng-deep to access the class text-area as in the picture?